# Matlab could not create any GUI, it always displays error

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I could not create any GUI in matlab ,even empty GUI , I deleted all old GUI files and I tried again but it display same message error:
"attempt to reference field of non-structure array ... "

error image:
[image: error image]

Any help?
Thank you

Comment: are you using GUIDE to create the GUI?

Comment: could you upload the files for your empty GUI? Would be interesting if something with them was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This could be the case of a corrupted preferences folder.

Usually when this corruption happens, some of MATLAB's interfaces refuse to launch. Examples of these problems can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/98438#answer_107788) and [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/36883-how-do-i-fix-an-out-of-memory-error-when-opening-simulink-library-browser-matlab-r2011b).

The solution for a corrupted preferences folder (as answered by the MathWorks Support Team) is:

1. Locate the MATLAB preferences folder by typing `prefdir` in the command window.
2. Create a backup of the directory and close MATLAB.
3. Delete the directory.
4. Restart MATLAB.